# Angular Universal ReferenceError - KeyboardEvent is not defined

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-universal, universal

I have added "domino" in the **server.ts** and even updated **webpack.server.config.js** as :

```
module: {
    rules: [
              { test: /\.(ts|js)$/, loader: 'regexp-replace-loader', options: { match: { pattern: '\\[(Mouse|Keyboard)Event\\]', flags: 'g' }, replaceWith: '[]', } },
              { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }, 
           ]
}
```

But still getting the same error : "ReferenceError  - KeyboardEvent is not defined".

I am running these commands in terminal

> $npm run build:ssr
>
> $npm run serve:ssr

Commands Defined in **package.json** as :

```
"build:ssr": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
"serve:ssr": "node dist/server.js",
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run angular.io-example:server",
"webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
```

Does anybody have an idea, how to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 7):

here you go

```
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const template = fs.readFileSync(join(DIST_FOLDER , 'index.html')).toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['Node'] = win.Node;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
global['Event'] = win.Event;
global['KeyboardEvent'] = win.Event;
global['MouseEvent'] = win.Event;
global['Event']['prototype'] = win.Event.prototype;
global['document'] = win.document;
```

Put above code into your `server.ts` file before the line

```
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP} = require('./dist/server/main');
```

Comment: Thank you. That gave new error: /dist/server.js:245610 ReferenceError: NodeList is not defined. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in server.ts

global['KeyboardEvent'] = null;

Comment: That did not work for me. Please, add details in your response.