# nativescript-angular - KeyboardEvent is not defined

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I'm trying to create a directive which will limit the decimal points to maximum two. So when a user inputs a decimal number, he can only enter maximum two decimal points.
It works in Angular but not in Nativescript Angular.

This is the directive that I created:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[nsTwoDecimalPlaceLimit]'
})
export class TwoDecimalPlaceLimitDirective {

  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowRight', 'Del', 'Delete'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const position = this.el.nativeElement.selectionStart;
    const next: string = [current.slice(0, position), event.key == 'Decimal' ? '.' : event.key, current.slice(position)].join('');
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

And the HTML part looks like this:

```
    <StackLayout class="form">
        <TextField class="m-5 input input-border" hint="Disabled" nsTwoDecimalPlaceLimit>
        </TextField>
    </StackLayout>
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: KeyboardEvent is not defined
```

Here's a **[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=9cbjD7&v=6)**

Comment: **{N} !== Browser**, there is no key press event out of the box, you will have to do it natively, by extending the delegate on iOS / text watch listeners on Android.

Comment: can you show me a sample? @Manoj

Comment: That's bit time consuming. If your problem is preventing user from entering invalid input format, then an easier option would be listening to text change event, if the value doesn't meet what you are looking for, update text field with desired value. That works for you?

Comment: It's not about preventing invalid input formats. I want to limit the decimal points to two digits only. @Manoj

Comment: Even that applies, check the length / characters and update the text field back.

Comment: @Lonewolf Did you check native script 'TextField' documentation - https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/text-field. It doesn't define if there any keydown event etc.

Answer (score 2):

In **goving** answer

https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830#issuecomment-345228799

you have to change in `node_modules`

```
angular-universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts
```

replace it

```
global['KeyboardEvent'] = win.Event;
```

check this also

[Angular Universal ReferenceError - KeyboardEvent is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650575/angular-universal-referenceerror-keyboardevent-is-not-defined)