# NestJs : Angular Universal ReferenceError - KeyboardEvent is not defined

Tags: angular, nestjs, angular-universal

Please assist, I have created an angular 8 project then added `@nestjs/ng-universal` to add nestjs as my server side, everything was running smooth until i added @ain/bootstrap our own custom ui boostrap components then received the following error  `ReferenceError - KeyboardEvent is not defined`, after searched and came across [Angular Universal ReferenceError - KeyboardEvent is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55650575/angular-universal-referenceerror-keyboardevent-is-not-defined) and https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts#L11. tried to implement domino to main.server.ts since i don't have server.ts and add `global.KeyboardEvent = null` in main.server.ts But still getting

```
    __metadata("design:paramtypes", [KeyboardEvent]),
    ReferenceError: KeyboardEvent is not defined
```

Is the a way to implement domino in nestjs main.server.ts file or solve `ReferenceError: KeyboardEvent is not defined` ? i dont want to remove @ain/bootstrap just want @ain/bootstrap not to affect nestjs.

Comment: I think the question, as it's currently written, doesn't provide enough information for it to be answerable. In this case, you may need to provide a little repository, showing your project and its dependencies, which can be used to reproduce the error message.

Comment: @TylerMumford added more info to my question hope that helps so that you able to help me.

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to help answer this question right now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Universal Nest](https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/universal-nest), specifically at the [`app.module.ts`](https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/universal-nest/blob/master/server/app.module.ts) file of the server side (server dir). This file implements domino to handle DOM object on the server as you should know, those doesn't exist on the server as mentioned on the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/universal#working-around-the-browser-apis).

Comment: Thank you, after applying `const BROWSER_DIR = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');
applyDomino(global, join(BROWSER_DIR, 'index.html'));`  in my `app.module.ts` I then added  `global['KeyboardEvent'] = null;` below since `applyDomino()` didnt have the global event and that worked for me.